# How to get alsa-lib on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, alsa

Apt-get is unable to get it, although I see that there is libasound2 installed, which is the same thing. I am trying to compile vlc from source, and it requires alsa-lib. Perhaps I could somehow use libasound2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to compile something from source that links to a specific library, you also need the appropriate header files (`#include ...`).  These are not included when the library is installed since they're only needed when compiling; instead, they come in small associated "development" packages.

On Raspbian these have a `-dev` suffix:

```
> apt-cache search libasound
[...]
libasound2-dev - shared library for ALSA applications -- development files
```

That's probably what you need.